# Setting iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8 in oscommerce / sts template website?

Tags: php, templates, oscommerce, content-encoding, sts-simple-templatesystem

In an oscommerce site I have the following:

Server response = Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

and I want:  Content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1

How and where do I set this up.

---

Html looks like this on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html dir="LTR" lang="nl"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Changing it to: utf-8 doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with UTF-8 (said differently, for which bad reason do you need to change?)

Comment: Because somehow the characters which aren't standard show up as boxes isntead of what they are supposed to be if I don't manually change the browser encoding to iso ...

Comment: Changing the type to utf-8 w/o changing the characters themselves will not fix it as you have seen.  You'd be better changing all pages to UTF-8.

Comment: As I've seen the accepted answer works for me, your "solution" won't work in this case.

Comment: http://forums.oscommerce.com/lofiversion/index.php?t105082.html

Check the last two posts on that page and see if they help.

Comment: Don't help, included more information in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in an .htaccess file

```
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: But stress again that migrating everything to UTF-8 is probably the better long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that (especially for a commerce site) you should use ISO-8859-15 instead, which includes the Euro sign.