# Issue with certain characters sent through mail

Tags: php, email, oscommerce

I have a site done in Oscommerce.

While sending the confirmation mails of products, in french, certain product names are not displayed properly in mails.

It is displaying properly for me, but for my client, it is not showing in the correct way.

What should I change to correct this issue?

For better understanding, attaching the images of mail.

This is the correct way: which is I'm getting

[image]

Following is the way it is displayed in clients email. The product with problem has been marked there

[image]

Comment: **utf8_encode()** function if `subject` or `body` have special characters

Comment: Message source would be more helpful, but this definitely looks like UTF-8 displayed in the wrong encoding.  The problem is not the lack of `utf8_encode()` because this is already in UTF-8, the problem is that the client is displaying it in ISO-8859-1 or something similar.  If the message lacks proper `Content-Type:` headers, or the `Content-Type:` disagrees with the content (presumably you have HTML, perhaps with a `meta` tag identifying a different character set) that would explain the symptom.

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of similar questions on this site; this is a common problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418650/setting-iso-8859-1-instead-of-utf-8-in-oscommerce-sts-template-website looks related.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the subject and/or message variable in the `utf8_encode()` function when you echo it.

Comment: I'm new to Oscommerce. Where should I do this edit? In which file? It is the mail associated with order confirmation.